# is it possible to move object between 2 `UICollectionView`

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview

i'm working with  `UICollectionView`, I have 2 collection. and I need to move object from the first one to the second by dragging.
my project is based on [LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout](https://github.com/lxcid/LXReorderableCollectionViewFlowLayout).

Is it possible to move object between 2  `UICollectionView` by dragging?

Answer (score 1):

Yes! (with a caveat)

You need to replace the delegate method willMoveToIndexPath and make a few modifications:

```
 - (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)theCollectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)theLayout itemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)theFromIndexPath willMoveToIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)theToIndexPath
{

/*  code removed from example code
id theFromItem = [self.deck objectAtIndex:theFromIndexPath.item];
[self.deck removeObjectAtIndex:theFromIndexPath.item];
[self.deck insertObject:theFromItem atIndex:theToIndexPath.item];
 */

NSLog(@"From: %d %d    To: %d %d", theFromIndexPath.section, theFromIndexPath.row, theToIndexPath.section, theToIndexPath.row);

    NSMutableArray *fromSectionArray = mySectionArray[theFromIndexPath.section];
NSMutableArray *toSectionArray = mySectionArray[theToIndexPath.section];
id theFromItem = fromSectionArray.myItemArray[theFromIndexPath.item];
[fromSectionArray.myItemsArray removeObjectAtIndex:theFromIndexPath.item];
[toSectionArray.myItemsArray insertObject:theFromItem atIndex:theToIndexPath.item];
```

}

I'm just writing the code here (it might have errors) but  I think you get the gist of what I'm doing.  I'm just adding one layer for section and not assuming that the "from" and "to" items come from the same section.

The caveat:
This code works but I'm having problems if the section is initially empty of items.

Hope this helps.